# Idempotent Design with Sidekiq Ruby on Rails Background Job

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, multithreading, sidekiq

Sidekiq recommends that all jobs be idempotent (able to run multiple times without being an issue) as it cannot guarantee a job will only be run one time.

I am having trouble understanding the best way to achieve that in certain cases.  For example, say you have the following table:

User
id
email
balance

The background job that is run simply adds some amount to their balance

```
def perform(user_id, balance_adjustment)
 user = User.find(user_id)
 user.balance += balance_adjustment
 user.save
end
```

If this job is run more than once their balance will be incorrect.  What is best practice for something like this?

If I think about it a potential solution I can come up with is to create a record before scheduling the job that is something like

PendingBalanceAdjustment
user_id
balance_adjustment

When the job runs it will need to acquire a lock for this user so that there's no chance of a race condition between two workers and then will need to both update the balance and delete the record from pending balance adjustment before releasing the lock.

The job then looks something like this?

```
def perform(user_id, balance_adjustment_id)
  user = User.find(user_id)
  pba = PendingBalanceAdjustment.where(:balance_adjustment_id => balance_adjustment_id).take
  if pba.present?
    $redis.lock("#{user_id}/balance_adjustment") do
      user.balance += pba.balance_adjustment
      user.save
      pba.delete    
    end
  end
end
```

This seems to solve both

a) Race condition between two workers taking the job at the same time (though you'd think Sidekiq could guarantee this already?)
b) A job being run multiple times after running successfully

Is this pattern a good solution?

Answer (score 3):

You're on the right track; you want to use a database transaction, not a redis lock.

Comment: Hey! Thanks for the immediate response.  I could put the balance adjustment and pending row deletion inside a db transaction but doesn't that not necessarily protect from multi-threaded concurrency issue where two workers both try to run the transaction at the same time?

Comment: It also seems like overkill / a lot of overhead to have to have some kind of PendingABC record for every job similar to this.  Is that really the best pattern?

Comment: It's common to have a Credit/Debit table which tracks the history of every monetary adjustment.  The "user.balance" column just becomes a cached copy of sum(PBA.amount).  I would use SQL rather than Ruby to do these things atomically. A single UPDATE statement is much faster/reliable than multiple network calls in Ruby.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're on the right track too but you're solution *might* be overkill since I don't have full knowledge of your application.

BUT, a simpler solution would simply be to have a flag on you `User` model like `balance_updated:datetime`. So, you could check that before updating.

As Mike mentions using a Transaction block should ensure it's thread safe.

In any case, to answer your question more generally... having an updated_ column is usually good enough to start with, and then if it gets complicated you can move this stuff to another model.

Comment: Thanks for the idea.  I think the issue with this solution though is now you have to introduce an arbitrary time limit on how often a column should be allowed to be updated?  Is that the idea?

So the job would check if the balance was updated within some small time increment from now and bail if it's under that threshold?

Comment: Also, with this solution you would still need a lock because two threads could still read the row before the timestamp is updated and both jobs would still run